# Why do the boundaries from RegionPlot not match the contours from ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, numerics, regions

When I try to plot a 2D interpolation, coloring areas with `RegionPlot` and adding contours with `ContourPlot`, the boundary given by `RegionPlot` and the contours from `ContourPlot` don't always agree. Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
dataList = Uncompress @ Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zUrJkXR4"];
area =  ConvexHullMesh[dataList[[All, 1 ;; 2]]];
dataList[[All, 1 ;; 2]] +=  
  RandomReal[10^-5*{-1, 1}, Dimensions[ dataList[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]];
  (* Recommended by Mathematica to avert zero-size triangulations *)
funct = Interpolation[dataList];
contour = ContourPlot[funct[a, b] == 124 , {a, b} ∈ area];
region = RegionPlot[funct[a, b] <= 124, {a, b} ∈ area];
Show[{region, contour}]
```

This produces

[image: Contours do not line up!]

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question without more information, preferably an example.

Comment: Perhaps increasing the number of `PlotPoints` in `RegionPlot`.

Comment: Here its considered helpful and polite show you own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly.

Comment: @rhermans Agreed. I now included a MWE. I do not know how to ideally display the data, though. The regular spoiler markup does not seem to work.

Comment: Pastebin is useful, look at [this question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1351/10397). I have edited it for you. You do it next time.

Answer (score 6):

A direct way to obtain the desired region, here superimposed on the total range of `dataList`, is

```
ListContourPlot[dataList, Contours -> {124}]
```

[image]

The faint background can be eliminated, if desired, by

```
ListContourPlot[dataList, Contours -> {124}, ContourShading -> {Blue, White}]
```

As described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Interpolation/udeg.html), the underlying cause for the poor quality of all these curves is that "currently no algorithm is implemented that allows to recover a higher-order interpolation on a list of unstructured points".

**Display in 3D**

The curve also can be displayed without difficulty on the three-dimensional surface representing `dataList`.

```
ListPlot3D[dataList, Mesh -> {{124}}, MeshFunctions -> {(#3) &},  BoundaryStyle -> None];
ListPointPlot3D[dataList, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[%%, %]
```

[image]

Superimposed are the actual data points.

Comment: A very nice suggestion. However, I finally want to create plots where I use different constraints and display an overlay what constraints apply to what region. I used to do this with RegionPlot, which allows for a convenient combination of conditions. I do not see how to recreate that behavior with ListContourPlot. Still +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is obviously `RegionPlot` is not doing a good job of discretizing the function.  I could not coax `RegionPlot` to do a better job. Here is one approach:

```
pts = Cases[Normal@contour, Line[list_] :> list, Infinity][[1]];
Show[{contour, 
  Graphics@{Red, 
    Polygon[Join[pts, {{1.38, 1}, {1.38, 1.38}, pts[[1]]}]]}}]
```

[image]

oh here's a better way..

```
ContourPlot[funct[a, b], {a, b} \[Element] area, Contours -> {124}, 
       ContourShading -> {Red, White}]
```

[image]

Comment: A very nice suggestion. However, I finally want to create plots where I use different constraints and display an overlay what constraints apply to what region. I used to do this with RegionPlot, which allows for a convenient combination of conditions. I do not see how to recreate that behavior with ContourPlot. Still +1